# Java String.getBytes() issue

Tags: java, pdf, byte, itext

I have an array of bytes. Irrelevant: I use the iText library and somehow parsing fails when trying to extract text from that array. I have traced the problem to be related to a corrupt PDF document (the bytes). So, I would like to edit the array of bytes before feeding it to the library.

```
byte[] bytesArray;
String x = new String(bytesArray);
x = x.replace("foo", "bar");
library.parse(x.getBytes());
```

How is this different from the following?

```
library.parse(bytesArray);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

- new String(bytesArray, "ISO-8859-1")
- x.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")

Explanation:

The constructor `new String(byte[])` and the method `String.getBytes()` use the "platform default character encoding" to convert between characters and bytes. Not all byte sequences can be mapped to characters in all character encodings. The constructed String will contain the unicode replacement character \uFFFD where unmappable sequences were found. The solution is to use a character encoding where every byte sequence is legal. One such encoding is ISO-8859-1. (UTF-8 for example would not work.)

Comment: Thank you, will give this a go and report back.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to provide feedback. Your answer was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: it's a shame Java doesn't provide a simple "raw" character encoding which means _"just give me the damned bits"_!

Comment: That's what the getChars method does--Java strings are defined in terms of 16-bit chars, not 8-bit bytes. If you want the equivalent byte array use the encoding utf-16le.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be an encoding issue - the `String` obtained from `new String(bytesArray)` will be using your default local character encoding, which is probably mangling the bytes in the range 128 - 255 into other characters.

The mapping is not necessarily 1:1, so converting back again may give you back a different array to the one you started with.

Answer (score 1):

You do not add the optional character encoding parameter:

- `new String(bytesArray, "UTF-8")`
- `x.getBytes("UTF-8")`

Indeed, if the platform encoding is UTF-8 and the bytesArray contain illegal byte sequences, you have a problem.

---

The following is a good byte replacer.

```
private void replaceBytes(ByteArrayInputStream in, ByteArrayOutputStream out, String from, String to) {
    try {
        byte[] fromBytes = from.getBytes("Cp1252");
        byte[] toBytes = to.getBytes("Cp1252");
        int fromN = fromBytes.length;
        int fromPos = 0; // Matching input, not written to output.
        for (;;) {
            int b = in.read();
            if (b == -1) {
                if (fromPos != 0) {
                    out.write(fromBytes, 0, fromPos);
                    //fromPos = 0;
                }
                break;
            }
            if (b == fromBytes[fromPos]) {
                ++fromPos;
                if (fromPos >= fromN) {
                    out.write(toBytes);
                    fromPos = 0;
                }
            } else {
                if (fromPos != 0) {
                    out.write(fromBytes, 0, fromPos);
                    fromPos = 0;
                }
                out.write(b);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: The bytesArray surely contains "illegal" sequences. :D
How to check the original encoding, if such a thing is possible?

Answer (score 0):

A PDF document is a binary file. It doesn't contain chars, and even less chars in the default platform encoding. Suppose your platform encoding is ASCII. All the bytes above 128 don't represent valid ASCII chars. So, when you tak a byte array and make it a String, half of the bytes (in average) just can't be converted to chars.